# Where can I download Visual Studio 2010 Web Express?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, web, installer

I'm searching Visual Studio 2010 Web Express, where can I download it ?

Edit:
All the search results for Visual Studio 2010 Web Express are redirecting to the latest Visual Studio (currently, 2015 and Community).

Comment: BTW, the accepted answer is straight from the first hit on Google for the search query `Visual Studio 2010 Web Express`

Comment: @Engineer Toast , all the search results for 2010 are redirecting to the latest Visual Studio (currently 2015 and Community).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

VS 2010 is outdated and no longer offered by Microsoft. The most recent version of VS is 2015 and its Community edition replaces Express editions of previous releases. [Download and Info](https://www.visualstudio.com/products/visual-studio-community-vs)